# java 7 for loop to java 8 IntStream forEach

Tags: java, java-stream

For the below Java 7 code,

```
public static boolean java8Test() {
    boolean flag = true;
    for(int i = 67 ; i < 79 ; i++) {
        if(!testBoolean(i)) {
            flag = false;
        }
    }
    return flag;
}
```

I want to write a Java8 code to execute testBoolean method for a range of numbers from 67 to 78 (both inclusive) using java 8 functionality.

Also, `java8Test()` should return false if `testBoolean` returns false, however the pocessing should not stop and continue for all the numbers in the given range of numbers.

I have already tried the below code but this code stop execution of testBoolean method after it return false which I do not want. I want the execution to continue and remeber the false flag that java8Test method can then return after all the range of numbers are executed

```
public static boolean java8Test() {
    return IntStream.range(67, 78+1).anyMatch(index -> !testBoolean(index));
}

private static boolean testBoolean(int index) {
    System.out.println(index + "\n");
    switch(index) {
        case 67 :
        case 68 :
            return false;
        default :
            return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: is that the actual code you want to execute in `testBoolean`?

Comment: testBoolean will perform some logic and return a true or false depending on the input integer.

Comment: Use `stream.ordered().takeWhile(...)` and give it your predicate. Then it will stop as soon as the predicate doesnt match anymore. Note that this method was added in Java 9.

Comment: On the note -  *"however the pocessing should not stop and continue for all the numbers in the given range of numbers"*, you might just be ending up mixing concerns of two different functionalities in a single method. Do revisit your design.

Comment: @Tiya - Here is a tutorial on java streams with text and videos - http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-functional-programming/streams.html. 

Here is how anyMatch works - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stream-anymatch-java-examples/.

Answer (score 5):

You could use an `IntStream` for the required range, call `testBoolean` for each value giving you a `Boolean` and then `reduce` the stream:

```
public static boolean java8Test() {
  return IntStream.rangeClosed(67, 78)
    .mapToObj(x -> testBoolean(x))
    .reduce(Boolean.TRUE,
       (aBoolean, aBoolean2) -> aBoolean && aBoolean2
    );
}
```

The reduction assumes that the result initially is true, and produces the final result by combining the initial value by applying "logical and" (`&&`) with each method call to `testBoolean`. So for each of the values from the given range the method gets called and the end result is false if any of the method calls is false, true otherwise.
When using method references, the above code becomes

```
public static boolean java8Test() {
  return IntStream.rangeClosed(67, 78)
    .mapToObj(Scratch::testBoolean)
    .reduce(Boolean.TRUE,
       Boolean::logicalAnd
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, even more elegant than my proposed solution :)

Comment: Thanks, and I liked the `filter` & `count` idea from your solution and the foldLeft variation.

Comment: `IntStream.rangeClosed(67, 78)` prevents doing the `+1` math and `.reduce(Boolean.TRUE, Boolean::logicalAnd)` would just make it further readable.

Comment: Thanks, I've changed the code to use `rangeClosed`. I am aware of the `Boolean::logicalAnd`, but refrained from using it, as the result becomes an `Optional` which then requires a conversion back to `boolean`.

Comment: With an *identity element* as in my previous comment `reduce` would still return an absolute type and not one wrapped with `Optional`. It's the same functionality as that of yours with a method reference for the lambda. Complete solution could look like - `return IntStream.rangeClosed(67, 78).mapToObj(this::testBoolean).reduce(Boolean.TRUE, Boolean::logicalAnd);`

Comment: You're perfectly right, seems that I omitted the identity element in my first attempts, I've amended my code.

Comment: @RalfWagner What is Scratch?

Comment: @Tiya That's the class where I tried out the code. Replace it with the class that contains the `testBoolean` method. (Your code sample did not include it.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't see much value in executing statements which do not change the result, but you want a terminal operation which consumes the complete stream, such as `count()`:

```java
IntStream.range(67, 78+1).filter(index -> !testBoolean(index)).count() == 0;
// or:
IntStream.range(67, 78+1).filter(index -> testBoolean(index)).count() > 0;
```

Alternatively, you could `reduce` your stream (think foldLeft):

```java
IntStream.range(67, 78+1).reduce(true, (result, idx) -> testBoolean(idx) && result);
```

Note that order of the operands of the logical and (`&&`) is relevant here, if you want to always execute your `testBoolean` function

Answer (score 0):

Using `IntStream` you can iterate between range and then use [anyMatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-) or [allMatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#allMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-) or [noneMatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#noneMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-) based on your requirement. There is no point of overriding `flag` variable with boolean value even after first match in for loop, so use `anyMatch` that will terminate the loop after first match and will return the value

```
!IntStream.range(67, 79).anyMatch(i->!testBoolean(i));
```

Comment: This doesn't work as expected because java8Test executes testBoolean till it finds a false and stops execution after that

Comment: You might want to create a solution based on `ordered().takeUntil(predicate)`, that would stop until the predicate doesnt match. I.e. what OP actually wants.

Comment: can you tell me what is your expected output ? `anyMatch` will terminate the loop after a match found @Tiya

Comment: I do not want the loop to be terminated. I want it to remember that a match is found and continue execution

Comment: You can go with other suggestions but according to my point there is no use @Tiya

Comment: Could be simplified to `IntStream.range(67, 79).allMatch(this::testBoolean)` besides the use of `range` instead of `rangeClosed` and the short-circuiting nature of `Stream` that would not process elements further once the result is inferrable.